# JSDoc: Typedef from literal

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, webstorm, jsdoc

Let's consider the following code, a function that returns an object with two functions:

```
/**
 * Create a something
 * @returns {object} Something
 */
function createSomething() {
  return {
    /**
     * Foo!
     * @returns {string}
     */
    foo() { return 'foo';},

    /**
     * Bar!
     * @returns {string}
     */
    bar() { return 'bar';}
  };
}
```

When calling this method, even though the return type is simply `object`, IDE:s like WebStorm will infer the type from the returned literal, so that typing `createSomething().` will suggest members `foo` and `bar`.

However, let's say I then need to pass this object around to other functions. For these functions to understand that this is a "something", I'd like to `@typedef` it, so I do the following:

```
/**
 * @typedef {object} Something
 */

/**
 * Create a something
 * @returns {Something} Something
 */
function createSomething() {
  return {
    /**
     * Foo!
     * @returns {string}
     */
    foo() { return 'foo';},

    /**
     * Bar!
     * @returns {string}
     */
    bar() { return 'bar';}
  };
}
```

Now we have a type for the object returned from `createSomething()`. However, because the return type is explicitly stated, the IDE will *NOT* automatically infer any members from the returned value, so we now have a defined type without any known members.

I can of course manually enter each member as a `@property` within the `@typedef`, like so:

```
/**
 * @typedef {object} Something
 * @property {function} foo
 * @property {function} bar
 */
```

However, this means having to keep the typedef in sync manually whenever I add or remove any members from the `Something` object.

I tried placing the `@typedef` just above the `return` statement in `createSomething()`, hoping that it would hint to JSDoc and the IDE that the typedef has the members defined in the following literal, but to no avail - a `@typedef {object}` seems to be always treated as having no members other than the explicitly stated `@property` ones.

Is there a way to let the IDE auto-infer the members from a returned literal, while at the same time defining a type for the returned object? Basically I want the same as what happens when using ES6 classes - it automatically becomes a type with all methods as members.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use [@lends](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-lends.html) tag for this before object initializer, like this:

```
function createSomething() {
  return /** @lends Something# */ {
    // properties
  }
}

/** @param {Something} s */
function f(s) {}
```

WebStorm understands this. Please note `#` sign after name in `@lends`.

Comment: I do however get a warning from WebStorm: `the returned expression type {foo(): string, bar(): string} is not assignable to type Something`, and it suggests changing the jsdoc to `@returns {foo(): string, bar(): string}`, which would defeat the purpose of using `@lends` ...

Comment: Could you please add more details on how to use `@lends`? I tried your solution and it did not work. (I'm using vscode).
do you still need to declare `@typedef {object} Something` somewhere? If I don't add it, vscode say "could not find 'Something'". If I add it, vscode say 'Something' is the same as 'any'.